# Measuring performance by MSE or RMSE in classification/clustering tasks?

Tags: performance, classification, cluster-analysis, mean-square-error

I employ K-means and MLP algorithms for two simple clustering and classification tasks.
I searched many in the literature and I found that some researchers applied MSE and other RMSE for comparing methods and their results.

Is there any logical and theoretical difference between MSE and RMSE in clustering/classification performance measurements?

For instance, if our dataset is normalized between [0...1] or is not normalized, which one is appropriate? Does MSE/RMSE depend on the normalization of features? or any scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMSE is the square root of the MSE.

Since the square root is a monotone function, you'll get the same ranking. Just the number has a different interpretation. RMSE can be more meaningful when you understand the data.

Don't use it for clustering. Use it for classification and regression only.

Comment: What you mean by `RMSE is a monotone function, you'll get the same ranking. Just the number has a different interpretation`. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: No, only the square root can be considered monotone, because MSE/RMSE are not functions in a single variable. What I'm saying is that obviously MSE(x) < MSE(y) if and only of RMSE(x) < RMSE(y); so they may not make a difference for your application at all.